# Waiting when using spmd (parallel computing) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, wait, spmd

I am using `spmd` to distribute two different tasks into the two processors of the computer. The code is something similar to:

```
spmd
    if labindex==1
       TASK_ONE;
    end
    if labindex==2
       TASK_TWO;
    end
end
```

Each task opens a file and processes it, storing the results. The loop continues while there still are files to process. My problem is that `TASK_ONE` has fewer files to process, and when it finishes, the code stops (it exits the `spmd` block). Thus, `TASK_TWO` does not finish processing all of its files. Is there a way to make that `spmd` keeps running until `TASK_TWO` finishes, even if `TASK_ONE` has already finished?

Comment: What loop? Is there a loop around the `spmd` block or are you referring to loops in your two tasks? I'm not sure there's enough info/code to understand what is going on.

Comment: What you observe is not a behaviour of `spmd`, it will always wait for all workers. There must be something wrong with your `TASK_TWO` causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `spmd` block cannot complete until all workers have completed, so if you are seeing that not all are files processed, you must have some other bug in your code. Essentially, each `spmd` block executes *as if* it had a call to `labBarrier` at the end.

You can easily see this behaviour like so:

```
spmd
    if labindex == 1
        for idx = 1:10, disp(idx), pause(1), end
    end
    if labindex == 2
        for idx = 1:3, disp(idx), pause(1), end
    end
end
```